# How to upload files using Yahoo uploader widget in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, stream, httpwebrequest

Many might have had experience using File Upload widget from `Yahoo User Interface library`. The docs and community all know how to receive the files on the server using another server technology other than `ASP.NET`. If anyone has indeed used the widget in their asp.net pages could you share the code on

1. How to receive the uploaded files Stream/Bytes to a file.
2. How to check Integrity of the File
3. How to check if file was received correctly.

Also i would love to do it in single page because doing so i would learn how to differentiate between a normal webpage request and the one caused my file upload widget

Yahoo Upload Widget can be Found here: `https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/`.

Comment: have you checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya wow Big name :) ,`PostedFiles` would contain only files uploaded by file input elements with name. Since the widget breaks down the File to bytes, it wouldn't show up under `PostedFiles

Comment: Technically it's broken into bytes every time as that's the only way you can send binary data, but I'm being pedantic. If you could provide a link to the widget, it would be helpful.

Comment: @SimonHalsey added the widget link. Have a look

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya you did answer right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question with code over here.

http://labs.deeptechtons.com/asp-net-tuts/how-to-upload-files-asynchronously-using-yahoo-uploader/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at postedfiles collection though? The API looks like it does a standard post. If it does, the just use that collection.

If it doesn't, then you need to use the inputstream property on the request object to read the incoming bytes.

Using something like Fiddler or firebug will tell you how it's making the request. Look for the request type being multipart/mime

**edit**
Checking the file integrity  & whether it was uploaded correctly are pretty much impossible. The only way I can think to do it is to have the user generate a hash of the file then upload the file & the hash & you check the hash is valid. ie not really practical.

All you're getting is a stream of bytes. you have to assume when the stream ends, it ended cleanly & you got all the file.

Comment: yup the posted files contain the files uploaded a quick sample proved helpful. btw could you answer all other queries too.

Comment: yup answered well. btw if possible you could add some code so that some others get the idea OR i could edit your answer to include my code? what do you say